# Bug count in Firefox releases

Tags: java, firefox, bugzilla, lines-of-code

From where do I obtain data related to **Mozillas Firefox's** release history?

I require

1. the **bug count** after each release version
2. **No Of comments** in the code of that particular release version
3. No of Lines of Code (**LOC**) of the same release version

I have to then calculate the **Comment/Code ratio** of **each release** version.
Once I have the ratio, then I could compare it with the bug count of that particular release.
This same process has to be repeated on all (or most) releases of Mozilla Firefox to get an average and provide a conclusion for my research. My final objective is to find out if the No. of comments affect the bug count.

I have done some research online and found out the following websites.

1. This will give me the LOC and No of Comments in a given month (Not a release version)
   https://www.ohloh.net/p/firefox
2. Bugzilla for Mozilla Firefox has some reports that I believe should solve my question, but I can't seem to find the correct values needed.
   https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/report.cgi

This doesn't have to specific to Mozilla, any other Open source projects are also welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just clone the repository and use something like [cloc](http://cloc.sourceforge.net). It gives LOC and comments for any project structure (as well as what language the LOC is in).

Then you just need to visit whatever issue tracking service they use to find the number of bugs for a given release. Releases are probably tagged in their SCM, so you could do this for any arbitrary project/release.

Firefox may be a little hard because they use one giant repo for nearly everything (Thunderbird, Firefox OS, etc.).

Comment: Firefox uses Bugzilla as their bug tracking system, but I can't find the no of bugs detected in a particular release :/